# "Did have" versus "had"

Tags: sentence-construction, auxiliary-verbs

In the following sentence, why have author used "did have" instead of "had" ? Is it grammatically correct at all ?

> I don't want to diminish her achievements, but she **did have** a lot of help.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. It's used for putting emphasis on the verb

Comment: @blgt I have another question about the sentence above, if you answer it, I'd be very grateful. Why has author used *have* after *did*? As far as I know *have* is used for plural nouns and pronouns, so in this context, it should be *has*, though

Comment: We use the infinitive form of the verb after `do`. Googling gave me [this page](http://www.grammaring.com/do-does-did-bare-infinitive) which has a couple of easy-to-understand examples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. *Did* is used emphatically.
Considering your case, the use of *did have* makes the sentence similar to

> I don't want to diminish her achievements, but she *had* a lot of help **indeed**.

The following sentences are fine:

> I **warned** Clara that it would be dangerous.
>
> I **did warn** Clara that it would be dangerous.

The second one suggests that the speaker was right about warning Clara as something has probably happened to her.

Notice that you can use the same structure with the present simple (*do/does + base form*)  :

> She *does know* how to make people happy.
>
> She really *knows* how to make people happy.

Answer (score 4):

When we want to give a sentence positive emphasis in English, we normally put stress on the auxiliary verb (including the normal use of the verb *BE*). The second examples in the sentences below are emphatic. The stressed words are in ***bold italics***:

- She's happy / She ***is*** happy.
- They've been helpful / They ***have*** been helpful.
- I can run fast / I ***can*** run fast.
- I'll finish my homework / I ***will*** finish my homework. I promise.

Notice that if we want to stress the auxiliary, we cannot contract it. For example in the first emphatic sentence we see "She ***is***", not "she'***s***".

Sometimes we have a small problem, because some sentences in English do not have an auxiliary verb. We don't usually see an auxiliary verb in normal sentences if we use Present Simple or Past Simple verb forms:

- He likes champagne.
- She looked happy.

When we want to make these sentences emphatic, we need to use the dummy auxiliary verb *DO*. This is the same auxiliary we use to make negatives and questions in the present simple and past simple:

**Questions**

- **Does** he like champagne?
- **Did** she look happy?

**Negatives**

- He **doesn't** like champagne.
- She **didn't** look happy.

**Emphatic sentences**

- He **does** like champagne!
- She **did** look happy!

In the emphatic sentences we see the dummy auxiliary *DO* being used so that it can take stress.

**The original Poster's example**

> I don't want to diminish her achievements, but she ***did*** have a lot of help.

That last clause is an emphatic version of:

- but she had a lot of help.

*DO* is being used as a dummy auxiliary here.

*Hope this is helpful!*