# 'I did commented on your post' vs. 'I did comment on your post'

Tags: verb-forms, auxiliary-verbs, emphasis

> I did **commented** on your post.

Is this a correct sentence?
As you know that we often make emphatic sentences by using "did"but when we make them we use 1st form but here 2nd form is used. 
I am just confused.

Comment: You have to use the *bare infinitive* **comment** after the emphatic do which is used as an auxiliary verb.

Comment: You mean to say,  this sentence is incorrect?

Comment: Typical mistake or typo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emphatic do-form with do as main verb](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78258/emphatic-do-form-with-do-as-main-verb)

Comment: Sorry,  it didn't help at all. I am talking about "Emphatic sentence". Is it possible to use 2nd form after "Did"in my sentence?

Comment: Another related question, [“Did have” versus “had”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49888/did-have-versus-had/49895#49895). Read the answers in this link.

Answer (score 2):

> I did **commented** on your post.

The sentence is erroneous. You should write:

> I did **comment** on your post.

The emphatic auxiliary **do** already expresses the past tense: **did**. The verb connected to **do** should be in the bare infinitive form, as Rathony has said.

---

Related questions:

- ['Did have' vs. 'Did had'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49888/did-have-versus-had/)

---

P.S. One possible source of confusion for the learner is that we can use **commented** after the auxiliary **have**:

> I *have* **commented** on your post.

This sentence is in the Present Perfect tense, and here the use of **commented** is correct.