# Intensifier do in the past tense

Tags: intensifiers

They did *create*/*created* the first representative government.

Which one is better? Different non-native people think differently.

Comment: [“Did have” versus “had”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49888/did-have-versus-had)

Comment: ValeraKundas - did you really mean to ask which one of ***create*** or ***created*** should be used (both preceded by ***did***)? If so note that we only inflect *one* verb for tense (***did*** here, so ***create*** must be left as a "bare infinitive"). But because you've mentioned "intensifiers" I suspect you're asking about whether to say ***They did create*** or ***They created***. In which case have a look at [Difference between “did + verb” and just “verb+ed”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118683/) (your question is probably a duplicate of that one).

Answer (score 0):

The verb the "do" is supporting **remains unconjugated**, in its *bare infinitive*.

> They did ***create*** the first representative government.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#Bare_infinitive

Answer (score 0):

**do/did** if followed by an unmarked infinitive when you use it for emphasis, s the correct sentence is:

> They did create the first representative government.